# How deep in my code should I be looking for troubleshoot a ZygoteInit ANR?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

It is my understanding that `ZygoteInit` listed on an ANR has to do with the app starting, so my question is, how deep within my code should I be looking for the ANR? `Application.onCreate()`? first `Activity.onCreate()`? should I go all the way to `onResume()`?

Just to be clear, the ANR with `ZygotInit` in this case doesn't list any of my code at all and I can't see any of it on other threads, however I do see things like preferences being read so maybe I can find the culprit that way. Here is an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjuyl.jpg

I should mention I can't reproduce any of these ANRs, they only show up on the Play Store Console.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, what you are talking about. I hope it's just about ANR. Is there way you can reproduce it locally?

Comment: No, I only ever see these types of ANR on the Play Store Console. I asked about this ANR before and was told that `ZygotInit`means the app is being initialized in those cases so I want to know how far that initialization goes, like when does it stop and moves on to a more normal stacktrace without `ZygotInit` in it? that would help me narrow down where the issue might be happening.

Comment: Zygote in your ANR trace means that the ANR is occuring when your app is starting up. It has nothing to do with Zygote itself.

Answer (score 0):

The trace says that your main thread is in a "Waiting State". And the place where the wait is originating is on a SharedPreference access during app launch. This is evident at Line No : 9 of your trace.

Comment: Yes but none of my code is on that trace or any of the other traces on the entire ANR report. So how can I know which part of my code is accessing `SharedPreferences` at that time? this is why I wanted to know which parts of my code run during `ZygoteInit`, so I can narrow down where I have to look a bit more.

Comment: Your code will not run ZygoteInit. Check to see if you are initializing any SDK on app launch or in your Application class that may be accessing shared prefs.

Comment: I'm doing lots of things on start up, most of which are required by various SDKs, which is why I'm trying to figure out a way to narrow this down. This specific trace shows `handleStopService` for example, I have one service but it doesn't run on start up, must less get stopped.

Comment: @Dinesh There is `Thread.sleep` in the third line of second trace. What you advice now, check, where he is calling `Thread.sleep`? Lol.

Comment: That `Thread.sleep` appears to be on the `FinalizerWatchdogDaemon` which I'm guessing is totally out of my control.

Answer (score -1):

First of all. `ZygoteInit` it's process . associated with a startup Android system right. However, it should nothing to do with your application. I think in your stacktraces, just trying to find all stack of calls staring from system launch. That is why it's possible to have `ZygoteInit` in your **and many other** reports.

If there is no way you can reproduce your issue, and/or no links to your application, I'm not sure we can go further. **Why you have it in your reports?**  Because of the nature of ANR. Let's assume it's startup of the system (again it's not related to your application), all apps trying to take monitor and allocate resources to launch their services. At this time, if resource of the system is not enough ANR will be sent to every process, who were trying to take it.

Comment: I see. I thought `ZygoteInit` was related to my app starting, not to Android starting. This explains a lot more, thank you for clarifying it. I'm now wondering why my app is running on startup if I don't have it set to do that, though maybe users are rebooting their phone and opening my app as soon as it reboots.

Comment: Wrong. Zygote is not a process to start up Android System.Zygote is a special process in Android which handles the forking of each new application process. These processes are simply regular Linux processes. We may think of the Zygote as the template process for each app and service that is started on the device. It is launched by the Android runtime, which also starts the first Virtual Machine (VM). The VM then calls Zygote’s main() method which causes Zygote to preload all shared Java classes and resource into memory.

Comment: @Dinesh That is what I have wrote in the answer. It's process associated with system startup. Besides spamming nosense, you could try to resolve issue.

Comment: "it's process to startup Android system right." Android System is not started by Zygote. https://medium.com/masters-on-mobile/the-zygote-process-a5d4fc3503db. You can read more about it here. This has good content.

Comment: @Dinesh It's almost the same in this context. I have changed from `for` to `associated`, so you can live now.